# How to use actual SASS file not SCSS in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I've been using SCSS in my current NextJS project. However, decided to switch to SASS files rather than SCSS. Because of clean syntax.

However, somehow I can't really find good example actually using SASS file not SCSS. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And it's not just loading in NextJS as well as the hot reload is not loading too when I try to import it like scss used to.

Comment: Does this help? https://dev.to/harveyjones282/the-simplest-way-to-configure-next-js-with-sass-3en